# How to use frame title font in the beamer text?

Tags: beamer, fonts

I want to use the title font in one of the frame's text (Not in the title) in a beamer document, How can I do this?

Comment: have a look at http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf

Comment: Try \usebox{\csname beamer@frametitlebox\endcsname}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle}` you can get both the font and the colour of the frametitle.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{text}

text

{\usebeamerfont*{frametitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{frametitle} text}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```